# Update Non-Vue-Object when Vuex Store changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Working on a music app in Vue & ToneJS, and I'm housing my ToneJS objects (ie: `new Tone.Synth()` etc.) on a module outside of Vue instances/components.

So my store looks something like this:

```
state: {
  tracks: [
    { 
      synthType: 'triangle',
      gain: 0.5,
      tune: ["beep", "boop", "bleep"]
    },
    {   
      synthType: 'sine',
      gain: 0.9,
      tune: ["boop", "boop", "beep"]
    },
  ]    
}
```

When the `tracks` object on the store changes in some way (for example, the user changes the gain on track 1), I then need to update the settings on the ToneJS synths.

How can I do this? I have been researching the `Store.watch` feature of Vuex, and I am frankly quite confused about both *how* to use it and *if* that is actually a good approach.

EDIT:

The "external" module (`AudioManager`, imported as `AM`) is currently just an object literal with two arrays, `synths` and `gains`. The parent component of the app runs this `dispatch` on `created`:

```
  initializeAudioManager: context => {
    context.state.tracks.forEach( (track, index) =>  {
      let trackSynth = new Tone.Synth()
      trackSynth.oscillator.type = track.synthType
      AM.synths.push(trackSynth)
      let trackGain  = new Tone.Gain(track.gain)
      AM.gains.push(trackGain)
    })
    AM.synths.forEach( (synth, i) => synth.connect(AM.gains[i]) );
    AM.gains.forEach( (gain, i) => gain.toMaster() );
  },
```

Comment: *How* are you using ToneJS? In a component? Can you show some code?

Comment: @acdcjunior Ok, that's how I get my `AudioManager` set up. Should I add any more info?